# flash player crashes when trying to enter fullscreen mode android 4.0

Tags: flash, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

So I've created an android app that plays video from blip.tv and various other flash-enabled websites. I use a `Webview` to display the video. Here is my code:

```
try{
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


        view = new WebView(this);
        view.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        view.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        view.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        view.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        view.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);


        // get the html code
        String html = getIntent().getStringExtra("VIDEO_CONTENT");

        view.loadData(html, "text/html", null);
        setContentView(view);
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
```

The problem is with android 4 (Ice Cream Sandwich). When I try to put the app into full screen mode, the app crashes. The app does NOT crash on android 2.3 or 3.0 however. Any ideas to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I think this is an android 4.0.2 / flash player problem, because other apps like `browser` and `dolphin mini` crash when flash is put into full screen mode.

Answer (score 4):

This happens in ICS because the `show()` method in `android.webkit.PluginFullScreenHolder` gets called when trying to go to fullscreen mode.  This method does the following:

```
WebChromeClient client = mWebView.getWebChromeClient();
client.onShowCustomView(mLayout, mOrientation, mCallback);
```

If you do not set the `WebChromeClient` on your `WebView`, you will get an NPE.

This fixed our crash, however the WebView disappears and the fullscreen video is not shown.

See: [Android ICS 4.0 Placing Flash WebView into full screen calls hideAll Method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181820/android-ics-4-0-placing-flash-webview-into-full-screen-calls-hideall-method)

*** Update:

Ultimately, in order to get my `WebView` to play flash videos in full screen mode I had to implement the `onShowCustomView()` method in my `WebChromeClient` in a fashion similar to what was done in the source code for the Android browser.  The implementation of that method that I used for inspiration was in the BaseUI class:

https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_browser/blob/master/src/com/android/browser/BaseUi.java

I don't fully understand exactly what is happening here.  I also wish I understood why the developers on ICS decided to require this method to be implemented.  I wish I knew the value, or what problem this solved.  In past versions, this fullscreen mode "just worked" now it requires a lot of digging.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem. I asked and got the following answer which works for me.
Hope this will help some people:

Create the FullscreenableChromeClient and
add this line:

```
WebView.setWebChromeClient( new FullscreenableChromeClient(this));
```

```
    public class FullscreenableChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        protected Activity mActivity = null;

        private View mCustomView;
        private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback mCustomViewCallback;
        private int mOriginalOrientation;

        private FrameLayout mContentView;
        private FrameLayout mFullscreenContainer;

        private static final FrameLayout.LayoutParams COVER_SCREEN_PARAMS = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        public FullscreenableChromeClient(Activity activity) {
            this.mActivity = activity;
        }

        @Override
        public void onShowCustomView(View view, int requestedOrientation, WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback callback) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
                if (mCustomView != null) {
                    callback.onCustomViewHidden();
                    return;
                }

                mOriginalOrientation = mActivity.getRequestedOrientation();
                FrameLayout decor = (FrameLayout) mActivity.getWindow().getDecorView();
                mFullscreenContainer = new FullscreenHolder(mActivity);
                mFullscreenContainer.addView(view, COVER_SCREEN_PARAMS);
                decor.addView(mFullscreenContainer, COVER_SCREEN_PARAMS);
                mCustomView = view;
                setFullscreen(true);
                mCustomViewCallback = callback;
                mActivity.setRequestedOrientation(requestedOrientation);
            }

            super.onShowCustomView(view, requestedOrientation, callback);
        }

        @Override
        public void onHideCustomView() {
            if (mCustomView == null) {
                return;
            }

            setFullscreen(false);
            FrameLayout decor = (FrameLayout) mActivity.getWindow().getDecorView();
            decor.removeView(mFullscreenContainer);
            mFullscreenContainer = null;
            mCustomView = null;
            mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
            mActivity.setRequestedOrientation(mOriginalOrientation);
        }

        private void setFullscreen(boolean enabled) {
            Window win = mActivity.getWindow();
            WindowManager.LayoutParams winParams = win.getAttributes();
            final int bits = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
            if (enabled) {
                winParams.flags |= bits;
            } else {
                winParams.flags &= ~bits;
                if (mCustomView != null) {
                    mCustomView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);
                }
            }
            win.setAttributes(winParams);
        }

        private static class FullscreenHolder extends FrameLayout {
            public FullscreenHolder(Context ctx) {
                super(ctx);
                setBackgroundColor(ctx.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent evt) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With the code above I finally made flash play videos fullscreen.